# EntityFramework 5 CommitTransaction for a context object

Tags: transactions, entity-framework-5

I see that EF 5 has a "BeginTransaction", but I can't get intellisense on the context for a commit. What good is having a BeginTransaction when there is no CommitTransaction? Am I correct what I'm seeing?

`DbContext.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)` is valid. There is no Commit for the corresponding statement above... Can someone inform me if this is correct? Without the Commit or Complete transaction, it won't get updated....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this:

```
var transaction = DbContext.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction();
transaction.Commit();
```

And this:

```
using(var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope()) {
   // do stuff
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Where did you find that `DbContext` contains `BeginTransaction` method? It does not. Transaction is managed automatically inside `SaveChanges` method. If you want to manage transaction yourselves you must use `TransactionScope` and call `SaveChanges` inside the scope.